# Ajax to Put Variables into MySQL database upon Facebook Like Click

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, facebook-like

I am trying to use Ajax to insert two variables into MySQL when a user clicks the Facebook like button.  Nothing is being put into the database table  The code I'm using is below.  Any ideas why nothing is being put into the database tables?

Thank in advance,

John

On file with Facebook Like button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
   $.ajax({
   url: "fblike.php", // the url of your php script
   context: document.body,
   success: function(){
      // if you want something to be executed when a result comes back
                      }
         });
});

</script>

<?php


session_start();

$uid = $_SESSION['loginid'];

$submissionid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['submissionid']);
$_SESSION['submissionid'] = $submissionid;


echo '<div id="fb-root"></div>';
echo "<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
echo '</script>";

echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">';

echo '<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>'; 

php?>
```

On fblikephp:

```
<?php




session_start();

$uid = $_SESSION['loginid'];
$submissionid = $_SESSION['submissionid'];


mysql_connect("host", "user", "pw") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());


mysql_query("INSERT INTO fblikes VALUES (NULL, '$submissionid', '$uid', NULL)");






?>
```

Comment: are you trying to add javascript before your html tag? maybe you should put it inside. in the head or the body forexample

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I wasn't doing it, so I tried it... but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Instead of echoing out all that html and javascript just put a php end tag before it. It will make your code readable.

Comment: i can't give u an answer right away because obviously there are other problems in your script. so here what u can do. format the html properly `<html><head/><body/></html>` and so on. then add an alert to your success function to see if you are making a correct ajax call first. then i can give you more details depending on the results

Comment: I added proper HTML formatting, and still nothing is being added to database.

Answer (score 0):

No offence, but I think you are completely mixing up Javascript and Server Side Script.

A basic intro to that concept is given in my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276766/getting-sql-data-back-into-javascript-after-jqery-ajax-call/6277312#6277312)

But to answer your question, in my opinion you haven't set up your PHP sessions properly.

You may be triggering the creation of two sessions. One will overwrite the other if you don't manage them properly, and you will lose your session variable values.

Try echoing the session variables, and try using an HTTP debugger (like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)) to find out which of your sessions is the LAST to be created.

Comment: How am I creating two session variables?

Comment: I've never been able to track down why this happens actually, but I see it often when using `session_start(); ` just on it's own. The way I found to do this was use `if session_start($PHPSESSID);` else `session_start(); ` I also like to force where my session cookies are set using `ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.yourdomaine.com');` but that's my preference, and then I can be sure that my session cookie is always being set where I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling FB handlers BEFORE you load their script